# JAVA - While loop exiting when it shouldn't be?

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements

ive been trying to fix this problem for myself for about 2 hours. I'm guessing someone is going to instantly spot out my problem. So my problem is that a while loop(or .equals is giving an incorrect result). Here's the code:

```
        Integer i = 0;
        while(!type.equals(questionArray.get(i).questionType) && Questions.hasQuestionBeenUsed(i)) {
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(i + " type=" + type + " - questionType" + questionArray.get(i).questionType);
        usedQuestionIndexes.add(i); //if question index has not been used - add it to used indexes
```

So the problem here is its exiting when the variable "type (string)" when it doesn't equal "questionArray.get(i).questionType (string)" which it shouldn't be. So lets say "type = 'hello'" and "questionArray.get(i).questionType = 'hi'" it is coming out of the loop?

The output from the code from the code above is this:

> > 1 type=general - questionType=sport

So what is the problem here? Why is it saying the first condition is true when its not? the second condition is saying false(which is correct) heres the code for the method "hasQuestionBeenAsked":

```
public static Boolean hasQuestionBeenUsed(Integer questionIndex) {
    for(Integer usedQuestionIndex : usedQuestionIndexes) {
        if(questionIndex.equals(usedQuestionIndex)){
            return true; //if index is found in usedQuestionIndexes array it will return that the index has been used
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks! If you need any extra info just tell me!

Comment: Why do you use Boolean and Integer when you should be using boolean and int?

Comment: Because you're negating the statement with a `!` => `!type.equals(questionArray.get(i).questionType)`.

Comment: @JustinJasmann but it needs to be looping until type does equal questionType?

Comment: But you just said above if you have "hello" and "hi" then `!("hello".equals("hi"))` is coming out of the loop. Expanded, that's `!(false)` which is `true`. If the other half of the condition at this point is `false`, you'll exit.

Comment: @JustinJasmann sorry yes you are correct, silly me. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime! Happy coding :)

Comment: These sort of problems can easily be debugged. Although there is plenty of help here, one should refrain from asking questions that can be debugged. If you are not able to debug it, print statements would point out what's missing.

Comment: But tell me this, why is this exiting with i at 0 when I have also added "&& i > 14" @JustinJasmann

Comment: If you've got an expression like: `(expr-1) && (expr-2) && (expr-3) ...` those **all** _must_ be true in order to _continue_ the loop. If any one of those conditions is `false`, you will exit. Therefore, if `i = 0`, then `i > 14` is `false`, you will exit.

Comment: Ok @JustinJasmann but with this statement:
>>while(type.equals(questionArray.get(i).questionType) && !Questions.hasQuestionBeenUsed(i)) {

why is the first condition returning true if type=general and questionType=sport ?

Comment: You need to read up on how to use a debugger. How do you know the first condition,`type.equals(questionArray.get(i).questionType)`, is true? If you're reading the values printed after the loop, then that condition was likely false.

Comment: ok @JustinJasmann I will read up on it! :) I've ended up just doing a for loop through the array with an IF statement inside it and now its doing what I want. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Haha, that'll get it! Good job :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple - it's because you are negating the false by using the negation operator - (!). So even though you have false, you are ending up with true because (not) false = true. In your case, use

```
// Remove the negation - !
while(type.equals(questionArray.get(i).questionType) && Questions.hasQuestionBeenUsed(i)) {
        i++;
}
```

Comment: But I want it to keep looping if type doesn't equal questionType?

In long hand
while type doesnt equal questionArray.get(i).questionType AND question hasnt been used keep looping